Why is my mediapipe not being installed, i am installing in pycharm
This error is showing when i am trying to install mediapipe. I already tried encoding and updating my pycharm. How can this be resolved?
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement mediapipe==0.10.11 (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for mediapipe==0.10.11
(https://i.sstatic.net/56TzI.png)

what is the install command you are using?
